# Hodge dual of differential forms $\Rightarrow$ de Rham cohomology and singular cohomology

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, de-rham-cohomology

We know that the de Rham cohomology is isomorphic to the singular cohomology, does the Hodge dual of differential forms induce a dual operation on de Rham cohomology, hence also on singular cohomology? Namely,

- Is the Hodge dual of a closed form also a closed form?
- Is the Hodge dual of an exact form also an exact form?
- Is there a Hodge dual of de Rham cohomology and singular cohomology?

Comment: The answer to the first two questions are no, and it's easy to construct explicit counter examples.

Comment: What is the Hodge dual of a function $f$ (viewed as a $0$-form)? When is $f$ closed, and when is its dual closed?

Comment: While the Hodge dual doesn't induce a pairing via closed and exact forms, it does preserve so-called harmonic forms, yielding a pairing. It's a nontrivial fact that the space of harmonic forms is in fact isomorphic to (De Rham) cohomology. Together, this gets you the classical Hodge thm on cohomology